# When given a position of an item in a list, how do I print that value?

Tags: python, list, position

I have a list with some numbers in it. The user enters the position of the item they want to print. For example:

```
 L = [1,2,3,4]
 input = 1
 output = 2
```

So the user wants to print the number in position 1 so the output will be 2. 
I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
input = int(input("Enter position: "))
for i in L:
    print(input[i])
```

Comment: Why not just `print(L[input])`? Also, don't override builtin names

Answer (score 1):

What about remove this loop and try `print(L[input])`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
input = int(input("Enter position: "))
print(L[input])
```

Comment: Also if you do that you overwrite the `input` function, so ideally, you want to call the input something else like `index = int(input('Enter position: '))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something simple like:

```
chooseFrom = [1,2,3,4]
choice = int(input(">"))
print(chooseFrom[choice])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the original code, try this:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
input = 1
output = 2
input = int(input("Enter position: "))
for i in L:
    print(L[input])
```

Your problem is that you indexed the input, not the list. This prints it 4 times just to let you know.

Comment: But if you want to go simple: `print(L[int(input("Number?"))])`

Answer (score 0):

List is a data structure which stores data using index number. suppose you have list called

```
l = ['a','b','c']
```

> Index number of 'a' is 0 , 'b' is 1 , 'c' is 2
>
> so list[index] will give you the element at that index.

```
l[2] = 'b'
```

> There for no need to use a for loop, if you already know the index
>   number.